# Calling a http Request in background failing inside dispatch serial queue

Tags: objective-c, asynchronous, httprequest

I have a http request to make whenever a new location has been found asynchronously, for handling request, i have create a class called background requester which takes care of all these requests. The following code sample is as follows.

```
- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager
    didUpdateToLocation:(CLLocation *)newLocation
               fromLocation:(CLLocation *)oldLocation
{
 dispatch_queue_t queue;
            queue = dispatch_queue_create("com.test.sample", NULL); //create a serial queue can either be null or DISPATCH_QUEUE_SERIAL


            dispatch_async(queue,
                ^{

                if (bgTask == UIBackgroundTaskInvalid)
                {
                    bgTask=[[UIApplication sharedApplication]
                            beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:
                            ^{
                                DDLogInfo(@"Task =%d",bgTask);
                                DDLogInfo(@"Ending bground task due to time expiration");
                                [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];

                                bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
                            }];

                }

                BackgroundRequester *request = [[BackgroundRequester alloc] initwithLocation:self.currentLocation];

                [request start];

                DDLogInfo(@"Task =%d",bgTask);

                DDLogInfo(@"bg Task remaining time=%f",[[UIApplication sharedApplication] backgroundTimeRemaining]);

                });

}


//background requester class

//the start function will inturn calll the callAsynchrnously method.

-(void) callAsynchronously:(NSString *)url
{
    DDLogInfo(@"Calling where am i from background");
    DDLogInfo(@"Url =%@",reqURL);

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url] cachePolicy:NSURLCacheStorageNotAllowed timeoutInterval:20.0f];

    responseData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    connect = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
    [connect start];
}
```

Comment: None of the http request hit the servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use `connectionWithRequest` from a background queue (without scheduling the connection in some runloop). Either

- use [`sendSynchronousRequest`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-BAJHAHGI) (which is fine to do if you're using it from a background queue like this), or
- schedule the connection in a run loop. If you dig through the [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) code, you'll see they create a run loop on a dedicated thread, which strikes me as the most elegant solution if you really need the [`NSURLConnectionDataDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSURLConnectionDataDelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html) methods.

  You can also use the main run loop (though I'm less crazy about that solution), e.g., something like:

  ```
  connect = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self startImmediately:NO];
  [connect scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSRunLoopCommonModes];
  [connect start];
  ```

  Also note, I'm not using `connectionWithRequest` (because that starts the connection immediately, which is incompatible with your calling of `start`; only use `start` if you use `initWithRequest` with a `startImmediately` of `NO`). If you try to do `start` in conjunction with `connectionWithRequest`, it can cause problems.

I think the `sendSynchronousRequest` is simplest (and saves you from having to write any of the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` methods, too). But if you need the `NSURLConnectionDataDelegate` methods (e.g. you need progress updates, you're using a streaming protocol, etc.), then use the [`scheduleInRunLoop`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001697-SW2) method.

Comment: when should i release the connect object?? ROb? just my small doubt please bare with me please

Comment: Can i use the same dispatch_async inside of which these requests happen?

Comment: @raghul The `NSURLConnection` is automatically retained during the duration of the connection, so you can make it a local variable of this routine and it will be cleaned up for you when the connection is done (if you use ARC). If you need the `NSURLConnection` for other purposes (e.g. you provide the user the ability to cancel the connection), you can make it a class property/ivar and then set it to `nil` in `connectionDidFinishLoading` and in `didFailWithError` (or if you let the use `cancel` the connection).

Comment: @raghul If you use `sendSynchronousRequest`, you don't need to keep a class property/ivar for the `NSURLConnection` at all.

Comment: I think due to its limitation, the suboptimal thread usage and memory foot-print, the only valid use cases for `sendSynchronousRequest` are testing, prove of concept, development and sample apps. Unfortunately, the next best cousin in the convenient API family `sendAsynchronousRequest` is just a wrapper around `sendSynchronousRequest` - unless Apple fixes that. IMHO, the  better advice is: use `NSURLConnection` in asynchronous mode and implement the delegate methods. Period. A basic implementation is just 100 lines of code.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper I agree that `sendSynchronousRequest` has limitations, I would have provided a completely different list of concerns (not cancelable, no progress updates, no streaming opportunities) because the typical "basic" delegate implementation is, in many ways, no better (or even worse) re thread usage and memory footprint. A proper implementation is more complicated than 100 lines of code, and if you're worried about the issues I enumerate above, you probably should just use [`AFNetworking`](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) or something like that.

Comment: Implementing a reliable and flexible "MyHTTPRequestOperation" class is certainly a challenge. But I'm also a bit reluctant to point to other third party libraries which may have their own issues, especially when I know that something really scares me. There are at least two other libraries - and the "original" from Quinn (Apple): `QHTTPOperation` which I would prefer over the one you mentioned.

Comment: @CouchDeveloper If you're open to it, I'd love to discuss offline on chat: http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31889/discuss-http-request-libraries-vs-nsurlconnection